# Org-mode don't change relative URLs

Tags: org-mode, org-export

How can I prevent Org from exporting `[[/][site root]]` as `<a href="file:///">site root</a>`?

Comment: What would you like it to export instead?

Comment: @nanny just the `/`.

Comment: Also, FYI, `/` is not a relative path. Relative paths don't start with a slash.

Comment: @nanny why not? Anyways, even if you think that only those which begin with a dot (or a URI Component character) are, the question is still the same.

Comment: My mistake, it is a relative url (but not a relative path, as in file path, I confused the two). I found something that may help: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html

Comment: @nanny's confusion might in fact be the culprit here. A slash is an absolute file path, and that's what org assumes it to be. You need to figure out how to tell org that it's actually a link.

Comment: @Malabarba it's an absolute path (path being a component of URL), but it's not an absolute URL (absolute URL would have to have a protocol part, a domain part and possibly other attributes). It is still relative (within domain). But I don't insist on this definition.

Answer (score 8):

OK, since I didn't find a ready-made one, I decided to roll my own. This doesn't seem to be difficult at all, so here goes:

```el
(defun wvxvw/export-rel-url (path desc format)
  (cl-case format
    (html (format "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" path (or desc path)))
    (latex (format "\\href{%s}{%s}" path (or desc path)))
    (otherwise path)))

(org-add-link-type "rel" 'browse-url 'wvxvw/export-rel-url)
```

Usage example: `[[rel:./foo/bar][foo bar]]` translates into HTML: `<a href="./foo/bar">foo bar</a>`.

The most important part is the `org-add-link-type` - this allows to specify the way to export the link. This code isn't universal, since it doesn't support even all the back-ends enabled by Org by default, but it should be obvious how to add more.

---

Starting with **Orgmode 9.0** the function `org-add-link-type` is deprecated. One should use `org-link-set-parameters` instead.

There follows the equivalent Elisp code for Orgmode 9.0. Note that the only change is the replacement of `org-add-link-type` with `org-link-set-parameters`. The function `wvxvw/export-rel-url` is unchanged. It is only cited here to ease copy-paste.

```el
(defun wvxvw/export-rel-url (path desc format)
  (cl-case format
    (html (format "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" path (or desc path)))
    (latex (format "\\href{%s}{%s}" path (or desc path)))
    (otherwise path)))

(eval-after-load "org"
  '(org-link-set-parameters "rel" :follow #'browse-url :export #'wvxvw/export-rel-url))
```

Comment: Please accept your own solution to mark this question as solved.