# How do I use org mode to export a link to a relative URL?

Tags: org-export

I'm exporting an org file to HTML that will live at `http://example.com/foo/bar.html` and also at `http://another.url/a/b/c.html`. I'd like to write some org syntax that exports links to other files on the same server.

Case 1. I want to link to another file in the same directory. How do I get output `<a href="data.txt">lore</a>`?

- `[[data.txt][lore]]` --> error "Unable to resolve link"
- `[[./data.txt][lore]]` --> `<a href="./data.txt">lore</a>` - good enough

Case 2. I want to link to a file in the root directory. How do I get output `<a href="/robots.txt">skynet</a>`?

- `[[/robots.txt][skynet]]` --> `<a href="file:///robots.txt">skynet</a>`, not what I want
- `[[../../robots.txt][skynet]]` --> `<a href="../../robots.txt">skynet</a>` - works only if I know how many levels up

Is there a direct way to output `data.txt` or `/robots.txt` as the link without getting `file://` prepended, and without having to use `./` and `../` as workarounds?

I see a different workaround on [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/org-mode-dont-change-relative-urls) but the function mentioned there, `org-add-link-type`, is marked Obsolete in org 9.0, and it's not obvious to me how to use `org-link-set-parameters` for this.

Comment: Maybe a [duplicate](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32601/how-can-i-get-with-org-store-link-relative-path-instead-of-absolute/32602#32602).

Comment: @NickD No that is not a duplicate. `org-link-file-path-type` only occurs in `org-insert-link` which has little to do with the export of orgmode.

Comment: I've added the version with `org-link-set-parameters` in [the answer to the other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9807/2370). That makes this question to a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @Tobias: thank you!